# Rect doesn't visualized after append

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

### Context

I'm using [react js](https://reactjs.org/) and [svg.draw.js](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.draw.js) for draw *svg* elements inside a *div*, the user can draw *rect* or other shapes and he can see shapes drawed in precedent session.

For make the last functionality I stored the entire *svg* element drawed as string so when *ComponentDidMount()* method is fired, it can parse it to *image/svg+xml* element and then it can append the *svg* node to the *svg* root.
So to try this solution in *ComponentDidMount()* I have create a *rect* node to append.

### Issue

When I try to append the *rect* element, it doesn't visualized but it's present inside the root element.

[This is what I see in console, the rect element is what I have to append](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjCd1.png).

### **Code**

This is what it's present in *ComponentDidMount()* method.

```
    componentDidMount(){

        /*
         *
         *irrilevant code*/

        const scriptDraw = document.createElement("script");

        scriptDraw.src = "svgDrawer.js";        //svg.draw.js 
        scriptDraw.setAttribute("id","drawer")
        scriptDraw.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(scriptDraw);

        var str = '<rect id="SvgjsRect1008" class="selected" width="124" height="89" stroke="#3399ff" stroke-width="2" fill-opacity="1" fill="#3399ff" x="236" y="160" name="dawdawad"></rect>'
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(str, "image/svg+xml");

        scriptDraw.addEventListener("load",function(){
            var map = document.getElementById("planimetriaSVG"); //svg root
            map.appendChild(doc.documentElement);
        })  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a namespace attribute to the rect element so parseFromString knows its supposed to be an SVG element i.e.

```
    var str = '<rect xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="SvgjsRect1008" class="selected" width="124" height="89" stroke="#3399ff" stroke-width="2" fill-opacity="1" fill="#3399ff" x="236" y="160" name="dawdawad"></rect>'
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(str, "image/svg+xml");
```