# Create svg on the fly and reference in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to create an svg element on the fly, adding it to the body and change the css stylesheet to reference a specific class property to the svg id.
The svg looks like this:

```
<svg id="svg" width="0" height="0">
<defs id="patterns">
<pattern id="pattern-1" x="0" y="0" width="8" height="8" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(-45)">
        <path stroke="#804040" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" pointer-events="none" d="M0 2h8"></path>
        <path stroke="#fff" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" pointer-events="none" d="M0 2h8"></path>
    </pattern>
    </defs>
```

And the css looks like this:

```
.pattern-1 {fill: url("#pattern-1);}
```

This work if I add these elements to the HTML by myself, but when I create the svg and css on the fly, the svg isn't added to my elements.
If i add the svg to the HTML and create the css on the fly it is working, so it seems to depend on the svg. Any tips how to accomplish this?

EDIT: I use these two methods to create the css and svg on the fly:

```
function createPatternCss(id)
{
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    var code = `.${id} {fill: url("#pattern-${id}");}`;
    var sheet = getStyleSheet("hatchstyles");
    if (style.styleSheet) {
      sheet.styleSheet.cssText = code;
     } else {
      style.innerHTML = code;
     }
     document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild( style );
}

function createPatternSvg(id, color, rotation)
{

  var patterns = document.getElementById("patterns");
  var pattern = `<pattern id="pattern-${id}" x="0" y="0" width="8" height="8" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(${rotation})">
        <path stroke="${color}" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" pointer-events="none" d="M0 2h8"/>
        <path stroke="#fff" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" pointer-events="none" d="M0 2h8"/>
    </pattern>`;
    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(pattern, "text/xml");
    patterns.appendChild(doc.firstChild);
}
```

Comment: How do you create them on the fly? add the code for this part

Comment: Adding the namespace to the svg did the job see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52566394/rect-doesnt-visualized-after-append